# LeanFT TestExportTool - Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, jar, manifest, leanft

I use `UFT 14.02` and installed `LeanFT` with same installer. `TestExportTool` gives error message below when I execute command:

java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LeanFT\Tools\TestExportTool\test-export-tool.jar" "C:\LeanFT\MyTestNGTests.jar" -classpath:"C:\TestNG\testng.jar"

> Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

I generated artifact with `IntelliJ IDEA` from `TestNG` test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsign the jar. Here's how I did that

1. Make a backup of the jar
2. If you have 7zip (or similar), you can open the `.jar` as an archive
3. Navigate to `META-INF` folder
4. Delete the signature files (e.g. `.SF` and `.DSA` files)

But there are other variances of this:

- [How do I unsign a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757083/how-do-i-unsign-a-jar/32623615)
- [Un signing a signed jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291978/un-signing-a-signed-jar)
- [Removing Jar Signatures in Gradle Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226033/removing-jar-signatures-in-gradle-build?rq=1)